# How can I auto run an application on startup when user input is needed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, startup

I'm trying to run an emulator on my raspberry pi zero and use it as a calculator. I want this to happen instantly after I boot up my pi, without being prompted for which image to run.

I want the emulator to run on startup and i looked into how to do that but all I could find was information about how to run a "script" at startup. I can run the script to start the application but it requires user input after that. You need to select an image to run and click ok, like this:

when i first run tiemu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z32q.jpg

after I choose and click ok: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzjjQ.jpg

Is there anyway to do that without the user input, so that the same image is always chosen and the emulator just displays the calculator after booting up, instead of the select image prompt. So can i get to the second image without going through the first one.
This might be a really simple question but I couldn't find any information on how to do it...

Comment: The best answer is always to write the program such that it takes scriptable input -- command-line arguments, f/e -- rather than unconditionally trying to interact with the user, *especially* via a GUI. It'll take you less time/effort to modify the source to the program to add that feature if it doesn't have it already than it would to try to automate the GUI interaction, and if upstream accepts the patch you offer, that approach will likewise be far more robust.

Comment: To be very clear, bash doesn't have *any* built-in functionality for automating GUI applications; it doesn't even have a *concept* of what a GUI is. As such, without 3rd-party tools (and without the program you're running accepting the same information that's prompted for via command-line arguments, environment variables, or another scriptable mechanism), what you're looking for cannot be done with shell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `tiemu --help`, you'll see [a list of command-line arguments available](https://github.com/abbrev/tiemu/blob/bc30541101fb8f6464963617e4b04774630ce9c6/src/misc/cmdline.c#L71-L92).

This includes `-rom=`, `-tib=` and `-sav=`.

There is no reason to try to automate the GUI when passing appropriate arguments prevents the GUI from being necessary at all.